# How to move laravel Kernel.php file to custom directory?

Tags: laravel

By default Laravel has `Kernel.php` file in the `app\Http` directory. How can be changed this class directory to custom directory?

When I tried to change class directory get error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does
>   not exist

Comment: But why? You are using framework like Laravel or other to proceed some patterns and directory structure. What advantage will you have after move it somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I use custom directory structue in my case @chojnicki

Comment: But kernel file still be in app directory, like all other app files?

Comment: Yes now `Kernel.php` file inside `app\Http` directory @chojnicki Generaly it's impossible moving file to another directory?

Comment: But I'm asking if you wanna it under another directory but still within app, like app\custom

Comment: Yes I want put class to `app/custom` directory or maybe `app/custom/subdir` @chojnicki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTICE**: This is not recommended. Like I said in comments, you decided to use framework like Laravel (or any other) to fallow patterns, directory structure etc established by framework authors. I do not see reason to change kernels directory, but if you really want to, then this is of course possible.

Paths to kernels are difined in `bootstrap/app.php`.

Change:

```
$app->singleton(
   Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
   App\Http\Kernel::class // here
);
```

To:

```
$app->singleton(
   Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
   App\Custom\Kernel::class // here
);
```

Now move `kernel.php` to new directory and change namespce:

```
namespace App\Http;
```

To:

```
namespace App\Custom;
```